# Damaged C17F SOT-23-6

Tags: power-electronics, identification

Can anyone help me with identifying this IC? I have no idea what it is.  I ordered one, but got a 5-pin one instead. It is from a hologram fan blade.

[image]

Comment: determine how the IC connects to U20 and U21

Comment: @ddawson Please provide dimensions of chip.

Answer (score 0):

since I see 2 identical chips on that board, I doubt that can be a voltgare regulator.

That chip might be a dual bipolar transistor.

If you have a multimeter try to find 2 diodes:

Read this:
https://www.fluke.com/en-us/learn/blog/digital-multimeters/how-to-test-diodes

Watch this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQpXBHEn09A

Or Google this "test a diode in circuit"

Post your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [Texas Instruments SN74LVC2G17DB](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809200013_Texas-Instruments-SN74LVC2G17DBVR_C10429.pdf) Schmitt-trigger buffer (or a clone).

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Buffer-Driver-Transceiver_Texas-Instruments-SN74LVC2G17DBVR_C10429.html))

Answer (score 0):

Probably a [SN74LVC2G17DBVTG4](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2302220000_Texas-Instruments-SN74LVC2G17DBVTG4_C2868212.pdf) dual ST buffer.

Image from [lcsc](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Buffer-Driver-Transceiver_Texas-Instruments-SN74LVC2G17DBVTG4_C2868212.html):

[image]